# How do I do login/logout over sockets using socket.io?

Tags: express, vue.js, socket.io

I want to do login/logout via websockets. It seems `PassportJS` is not made for this.

Can I simply make a `login` and `logout` event?

I'm building a `SPA` using `Vue`, so I'd prefer to do everything without reloading the page.

What are my options?

Comment: Look into routing and AJAX.  Start users on a login route, validate in the backend with AJAX, get the result in the frontend, and redirect to a different route if validated.

Comment: Okay, so don't use socket.io for login/logout? After thinking about it, it does seem like it would be easier to use passport, set up some HTTP endpoints for login/logout, and just use something like `vue-authenticate` which uses AJAX requests. I guess now I'm just wondering if there's any reason not to use websockets

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use Socket IO to develop real time applications. For login logout either use JWT token or NodeJS.